# GestureDectector onTap being immediately called on build (web output)

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I am trying to use the following code to add a simple display of all emoji out of a list I've pre-loaded into a model object. However, when I run this code in web output, the onTap listener is immediately called for every single GestureDetector added. And I'm not sure why?

```
class EmojiKeyboard extends StatefulWidget {
  

  EmojiKeyboard();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _EmojiKeyboardState();
}

class _EmojiKeyboardState extends State<EmojiKeyboard> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  _emojiTapped(String emoji) {

    print(emoji);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //i load the list of emoji from a model object in my real code, simplifying here to not distract from the issue
    List<String> listEmoji = [];
    List<Column> columns = [];
    List<Widget> children = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < listEmoji.length; i++) {
      var emoji = listEmoji[i];

      children.add(GestureDetector(
          child: Text("${emoji}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 36,
                  fontFamily: Emoji.getFontNameForPlatform())),
          onTap: _emojiTapped("$emoji"))
          
          );

      if (i % 4 == 0) {
        columns.add(Column(
          children: children,
        ));
        children = [];
      }
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: columns,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not correctly passing a function to `onTap`. What you're currently doing is calling and passing the return value of `_emojiTapped("$emoji")` to `onTap`. You need to create an anonymous function to pass to `onTap` that then calls `_emojiTapped`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //i load the list of emoji from a model object in my real code, simplifying here to not distract from the issue
    List<String> listEmoji = [];
    List<Column> columns = [];
    List<Widget> children = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < listEmoji.length; i++) {
      var emoji = listEmoji[i];

      children.add(GestureDetector(
          child: Text("${emoji}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 36,
                  fontFamily: Emoji.getFontNameForPlatform())),
          onTap: () {
              _emojiTapped("$emoji");
          })
          
          );

      if (i % 4 == 0) {
        columns.add(Column(
          children: children,
        ));
        children = [];
      }
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: columns,
        ));
  }
```

Comment: thanks christopher, definitely a little rusty with flutter right now